# Is it possible to store a character in an array which is defined as an integer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, integer

How could the array defined as `int` store the string values? Just look at the code, `arri[]` is defined as an integer but storing string values? And also the array defined as a character is storing integer values. How is this possible?

```
int main(void) {
    int arri[] = {'1' , '2', 'a'};
    int *ptri = arri;
    char arrc[] = {11, 21 ,  31 };
    char *ptrc = arrc;
    printf("%d" , *arri);
    printf("%d" , *ptri);
    printf("%d" , *arrc );
    printf("%d" , *ptrc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using the term "string" wrong here. There's no strings in the code you show, only *characters* which are typically [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` values anyway.

Comment: Because characters are really just  numbers inside the machine. For instance you don't store the character `'a'`. Instead you store some number which represents the character.

Comment: `char` and `int` are both integer types. Characters in C are merely numbers that are codes for the characters. The numbers are integers that fit in a `char`. They also fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> How could the array defined as int store the string values?

There are no strings in the code snippets you provided.

In this declaration

```
int arri[] = {'1' , '2', 'a'};
```

the initializers that represent integer character constants having the type `int` are used to initialize elements of the array. These character constants are stored internally as their codes. For example in the ASCII character table the integer character constants internally have correspondingly values 49, 50, and 97.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int arri[] = {'1' , '2', 'a'};
    const size_t N = sizeof( arri ) / sizeof( *arri );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "'%c' = %d ", arri[i], arri[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
'1' = 49 '2' = 50 'a' = 97
```

When the conversion specifier `%c` is used the function `printf` tries to output them as (graphical) symbols.

Pay attention to that when the conversion specifier `%d` is used to output an object of the type `char` then there is performed the integer promotion that promotes the object of the type `char` to an expression of the type `int`.

In this declaration

```
char arrc[] = {11, 21 , 31 };
```

the integer constants have values that fit into the range of values that can be stored in an object of the type `char`.

In the both cases there is no truncation or overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to make clear is that don't actual store a character like `'a'` anywhere inside the computer. You actually store a number. For `'a'` that number is decimal 97. The computer itself has no knowledge about this being an `'a'`. The computer only sees it as a number. It's only when you send that number to a device expecting characters (e.g. a terminal, a printer, etc) that some device driver changes the number to display of the character `'a'`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for a description of the mapping between charcters and numbers.

The C standard allows you to use characters just as-if they were numbers. The compiler automatically converts the character to the corresponding number. Therefore

```
int x = 'a';
```

is exactly the same as

```
int x = 97;
```

and your line

```
int arri[] = {'1' , '2', 'a'};
```

is the same as

```
int arri[] = {49 , 50, 97};
```

As already mentioned the type `char` is just storing numbers - just like the type `int`. The difference is just the range of numbers that can be stored. Typically a `char` is 1 byte of memory and `int` is 4 bytes (but it's system dependant).

So this code

```
char arrc[] = {11, 21 ,  31 };
```

simply stores those 3 decimal numbers. Typically using 1 byte for each number.

The interresting part is this line:

```
printf("%d" , *arrc );
```

Here `*arrc` is the number 11 stored in 1 byte (typically). So how can it be printed using `%d` which expects an `int` ?

The answer is "Default argument promotions". For variadic functions (like `printf`) this means that integer types "smaller" than `int` shall be converted to `int` before the function call. Note that `char` is considered an integer type so this also applies for `char`.

So in your case the number 11 stored in `char` (1 byte) will automatically be converted to the number 11 stored in `int` (4 bytes). Consequently the `printf` function will receive an `int` and will be able to print is as such.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
int foo = 3.14159;
```

the `double` value is automatically converted to `int` (to `3`) [implicit conversion]. There is nothing that prohibits the conversion, so the assigment ("of a `double` to an `int`") is ok.

Same thing with your example

```
char foo = 65; // the int value is implicitly converted to type char
char bar[] = { 66, 67, 0 }; // 3 conversions ok
char baz = 20210914; // possibly erroneous conversion from int to char
                     // in this case the compiler will, probably, warn you
                     // 20210914 is beyond the range of char, so this is, technically, UB
```

Note that

```
int a = 'b';
```

the `'b'` above is a value of `int` type, so there really is no conversion.

```
char b = 'c'; // implicit conversion from int to char ok
int c = b; // implicit conversion from char to int ok
```